# Autowiring @Bean within @Component

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I can achive the following in the xml:

```
<bean id="bean1" class="com.test.Class1"/>

<bean id="bean2" class="com.test.Class2">
    <property name="bean1" ref="bean1"/>
<bean/>
```

My goal is to implement the following on Java.

I've tried the following:

```
@Component
class GeneralClass{

@Bean
    public Class1 class1() {
        return new Class1();
    }

@Bean
    public Class2 class2() {
        return new Class2(class1());
    }
}
```

But, I am not sure whether it was correct one.

Will be good to know how it should be achieved within @Component.

Comment: Do you have `<ctx:annotation-config>` in your xml? Or how do you use your `GeneralClass`? In general it's not recommended to use `@Bean` in the `@Component`, it is a responsibility of `@Configuration`, although it works. If you have correct environment though

Comment: My application context creating via @Configuration. So, I can move the following beans to it. But, I am stil not sure: 1) Whether it will be correct autowiring like this: "new Class2(class1());". 2) Should we create class1 as bean in the following case or it can be simple as class2.setBean1(new Class1()); Thanks.

Comment: It depends on your components, if `Class1` really has to be a bean and it might be available for other beans (via inject), so configure it as a `@Bean`. Otherwise, of course, you can `new Class1()` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `@Component` with `@Configuration` and make sure the Configuration class is being picked up by component scanning